# Lenguaje apropiado para un taller informático

Tags: vocabulario, verbos, vocabulario-técnico, tiempos-verbales

Tengo la necesidad de preparar un instructivo para un taller informático, más conocido como **workshop** y quiero saber qué **tiempo y modo verbal** utilizar para trasmitir las ideas a fines al taller. 
En un workshop se busca dado un objetivo, lograrlo durante la duración del taller. 
Ejemplo: "Configuración y primeros pasos en Matlab"

Saludos

Comment: Supongo que yo usaría 1 persona del plural e indicativo: "abrimos la interfaz; tecleamos XYZ en la línea de comandos; Hacemos _click_ en _run_ y vemos en la consola nuestro <<Hola Mundo>>", pero creo que no entiendo bien cuál es el objetivo del taller. Una explicación un poco más detalla del mismo te proporcionará más y mejores respuestas.

Comment: Hola Diego ,gracias por comentar, no mencioné el objetivo del taller. En un workshop se busca dado un objetivo , lograrlo durante la duración del taller. Lo que no estoy seguro es si usar un vocabulario blog / tutorial, que sería el que mencionas vos , o algo más formal como trabajo de investigación, o existe algo intermedio entre la primera persona  y la 3ra. Saludos

Comment: Hola! Afín, plural afines, de escribe todo junto. La última frase (en un workshop, se...) no es correcta sintácticamente. Un placer ayudar.

Comment: Se puede arreglar de varias formas, pero quizá yo escribiría, en un Workshop se busca lograr un objetivo dado durante la duración del taller; aunque durante la duración es muy redundante (repetitivo)

Comment: Si quieres mantener la frase en ese orden tienes que colocar bien las comas, haciendo algún ajuste: en un Workshop se busca, dado un objetivo, lograrlo (aunque quizá mejor: lograr dicho objetivo) durante el taller (quédate sin "duración")

Comment: Aunque al escribirlo así, quieres hacer una referencia a un objeto que mencionas en una aclaración, y para que se entienda tienes que ser redundante (lograr dicho objetivo), y creo que no es del todo correcto.

Comment: En mi primer comentario quise poner "se escribe", y no "de escribe"

Comment: Estas son instrucciones que va a leer en vos alta o instrucciones que los usuarios van a seguir individualmente?

Comment: @JuanRocamonde gracias por comentar, pero no apuntaba a expresar esa frase, solo hago alusión  a lo que significa un workshop para contextualizar la pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Desde luego, simplemente pretendía ayudar :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que es un taller, yo usaría el estilo blog o tutorial. No estás haciendo una presentación, sino involucrando a los participantes, así que dejaría de lado estilos más asociados a academia (investigación).

Esa es además una poderosa razón para usar primera persona del plural. Usando "(Nostros) hacemos, escribimos, *clickamos*, vemos, etc." consigues una cercanía con el público que no consigues con la primera persona del singular o con segunda persona.

Acerca del tiempo verbal, presente de indicativo funciona bien en estos casos. Vemos ejemplos en recetas de libros de cocina, tutoriales paso a paso, etc.

Answer (score 1):

En todo lo referente a programación, sobre todo si es el comienzo, la experiencia previa en el campo aunque sea con otros lenguajes tiene mucho que ver.

Sin embargo, dado que hay un objetivo a cumplir y normalmente está bien ajustado al tiempo, no suele haber mucho lugar para extenderse, andarse por las ramas o confundir ni siquiera un poco a los participantes.

Más que el tiempo verbal, que simplemente debería ser una primera persona plural del indicativo(tono amable y agradable, ante todo!!), me centraría en el flujo del curso y en los puntos en los que más conflicto pueda surgir para solucionarlos rápidamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder David, y por los consejos los voy a tener en cuenta

Answer (score 1):

Yo, personalmente utilizaría el tiempo presente y la primera persona del plural cuando haya que indicar paso por paso lo que los alumnos tienen que hacer en sus ordenadores. 
Cuando hables de la programación en sí, creo que el impersonal es el modo más correcto, al fin y al cabo te refieres a lo que "se hace" en programación y no lo que "hacemos".